# Facebook share with link, title, description and image android

Tags: android

I am trying to share some data over Facebook through below code but it is not displaying.

```
ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(BillsDetailWebActivity.this);
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle(billTitle)
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("some image uri"))
                .setContentDescription("some desc")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(preferenceManager.getURL()))
                .build();
shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);
```

Any help to just add these details once shared over FB?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you following Facebook doc step by step?

Answer (score 1):

As of **April 18, 2017**, the following parameters are no longer supported by Graph **API versions 2.9** and higher. For versions **2.8** and lower, the parameters will continue working until **July 17, 2017**.

- contentTitle
- imageURL
- contentDescription

These params not supported by Facebook anymore.

For more info go to this [Facebook Official doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

Comment: yes I know that but in new API how can we achieve same things?

Comment: @BinayKumarRana read the document I posted the link with answer